# Unity Missing Metadata File on Gradle

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

When I try to build my APK, it gave me this error. Does anyone knows how to fix it? I'm, pretty much a noob at this..

This is the error:
Failed to deserialize script metadata extracted for settings file 'E:\Unity\ViVi Rewards App\Temp\gradleOut\settings.gradle'

> C:\Users\joben.gradle\caches\6.1.1\scripts-remapped\settings_8m8cvmop170ye4re55n78cmiz\4jsmw4m4g4tdgvfqt2iiilune\cp_settings3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87\metadata\metadata.bin (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Drop the space in the folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I managed to solve the issue by deleting the .gradle file in my c drive and rebuild again in unity.